# Avoiding identical commits in git

Tags: git, git-merge

Thanks for all help in advance.

Here is a situation and I am trying to understand if git provides a way around  this:

Two users (U1 and U2) each have a local repo that is synced to the tip.

U1 makes a change and commits this change and pushes to the remote.
U2 makes the EXACT same change and commits. But when he tries to push, he cannot. 
So he does git pull (without the rebase). Now git has added a "merge branch master' message.
Now if U2 now pushes, his commit (which was the exact change done by U1) again gets pushed to the remote.

Is there a way to avoid this? Am I missing some key command here?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the solution (potentially dangerous). Secondly, a possibly unnecessary warning on how to use git:

### Dangerous solution

#### Step 1: Rebase.

(Difficulty: medium --- Danger: medium)

Use the command `git rebase -i <something>` where `<something>` indicates a commit, like a commit SHA or HEAD~4 (replace 4 with the number of commits to interactively rebase). The command opens an editor with a few paragraphs explaining how to use interactive rebase. You can delete the duplicate commits from there very easily, but you should save off your branch to another branch for safety. `git rebase -i` is a very useful command/switch to learn how to use.

#### Step 2: Force push.

(Difficulty: low --- Danger: high)

`git push origin <branch name> --force` to push your changes. This is dangerous because anyone who pulls from that branch will be out of sync, and will need to delete their branch and re-fetch it. They should follow **step 2a**. If no-one else uses that branch apart from you, it is safe to force push.

#### Step 2a: Update everyone else.

(Difficulty: medium --- Danger: medium)

```
git branch -D yourbranch # Delete your branch
git checkout origin/yourbranch # Check out the remote-tracking branch
git checkout -b yourbranch # Recreate the branch
```

CI tools that integrate with GitHub should be unaffected.

### Warning

You should use `git-flow` or some similar process. Your two users should not be pushing to the same branch or you will get merge conflicts all the time. Also, don't rebase any commit that has been merged into master or that multiple people will have pulled from. If you force push, then you need to apply **step 2a** to every branch on every repo on every machine that has the rebased commit merged into it. A nightmare if you rebase a commit that was in master.

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter if the change is exactly same, since a git's commit object (and its SHA1) is created not only based on the actual diff, but also the author, committer, the commit message, the timestamp of the commit and so on.

Since U2 does a `pull` (i.e. a fetch + merge) and not a `pull --rebase` (i.e. a fetch + rebase), you would get a new merge commit, and this is still a change (even if it does not involve any changes in the state of the work-tree itself), and hence will be pushed to the remote. The diagram below should show exactly what is happening in your case.

```
State of remote(say origin)
U1C1 -- U2C2

State of U1 on start
U1C1 -- U2C2

State of U2 on start
U1C1 -- U2C2

U1 after creating a new commit
U1C1 -- U2C2 -- U1C3

U2 after creating a new commit
U1C1 -- U2C2 -- U2C3'

Remote after U1 pushes the change
U1C1 -- U2C2 -- U1C3

U2 after git pull (Merging origin/master into master)
U1C1 -- U2C2 -- U2C3' -- U2C3"
             \          /
              \ U1C3 --/

Remote after U2 does a git push
U1C1 -- U2C2 -- U2C3' -- U2C3"
             \          /
              \ U1C3 --/
```

If U2 had done a `git pull --rebase` instead, U2 would have at least noticed a conflict, and hence would have backed off his/her commit.

There are tools like [`git-flow`](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) that users could use for managing git workflows. If you use something like gitolite on the remote's bare repo, there could be some settings there to control or reject the `push` operation for few cases.

You might be able to fix this one-time by rewriting history, but once a commit is made public, it is a bad idea to rewrite history, since there would be users who might still have the older history and they would start seeing a diverged history.